# Need help to implement HTML5 page preload just like David Walsh's blog

Tags: html, preload

I hope, you guys have seen David Walsh Blog. The address is davidwalsh.name

I want to implement the same kind of page preload feature which the blog uses. I have read the blog post written by David Walsh himself on HTML 5 Page Preload. However, I have tried several times following his guidelines and other Stackoverflow threads. My page indeed preloads (as I can see in my Firebug Network tab), but when I click the page link on my current page, the page reloads from server. It doesn't just render the already loaded page. And if you look at David Walsh's site, it looks like a AJAX load, however the page URL changes.

Am I missing something on caching part to implement a AJAX call look-alike preload? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I still don't understand enough about your situation to know what didn't work, and why. If you followed the specs, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Have you seen David's blog? When you click a link, the page fades, the browser doesn't show page load progress, the previous page content never turns white before loading the next page. And then simply the URL changes in the browser address bar and the new page content is displayed in browser viewport. In my case, it doesn't go like that - I see a normal page load. And yes, to clearly identify that my page reloads second time (instead of using prefetch link attribute) from server, I am verifying my server logs; and I see the second request in log.